# Oracle SQL Developer stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

```
create table emp as
  select 7782 empno, 'CLARK' ename from dual;
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE emp
    (empno CHAR(20),
     ename CHAR(20))
  ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
insert into   emp
(empno,ename) values('1','CLARK');

select * from emp;
create or replace procedure details (p_cursor out sys_refcursor)
is
begin
  open p_cursor for
    select empno, ename
    from emp;
end;
/

declare
  rc sys_refcursor;
  l_empno emp.empno%type;
  l_ename emp.ename%type;
begin
  details (rc);
  loop
    fetch rc into l_empno, l_ename;
    exit when rc%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_empno||' - '|| l_ename);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Using Oracle SQL Developer I create the script above hoping to see result but I dont see any result from the query all I see is

[image]

How to print/show result

Comment: you have 2 create statements, both creating same object EMP .. as provided, the 2nd create global temporary table fails, because you already have a table named EMP ?

Also  note, that once you compile/create that package, your session applies an implicit COMMIT, which will then result in your global temporary table (if it's created instead of the other one) to lose all its records.

I feel your test case is a bit flawed .. so hard to put together what you're trying to do ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the output is disabled. You can enable it with :

```
set serveroutput on
```

Comment: should i run this together with the script?

Comment: @guradio It needs to enabled only once, but you can run it together.

Comment: I still dont get the result All I see is 

`1 row inserted.

>>Query Run In:Query Result

Procedure DETAILS compiled


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


1 row inserted.


Procedure DETAILS compiled


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.`

Comment: @guradio `create or replace procedure` is a DDL statement. A DDL statement implicitly commits the current transaction. The rows from your GTT were automatically deleted because of `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS`.

Comment: I see let me check again on this